# Unable to load config data from '--spring.profiles.active=local'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I am running the below command to run by SPring boot application.How can i resolve it.I have the necessary files present in `/path/config/`.

> mvn spring-boot:run
> -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.config.location=../path/config/,--spring.profiles.active=local,
> --spring.active.profiles=local"

But i am getting the below error

```
13:51:14.064 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from '--spring.profiles.active=local'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:128)
```

Comment: Have you tried a full path instead. Alternatively `classpath:../path/config/` or similar with correct path

Comment: The configuration for the given profile `application-local.yml` does not exist?

Comment: yes the configuration exist

Comment: @grekier yes but its giving same error

Comment: In short, the application cannot find the properties files (or yml) so it is either a file missing or the path that is not correct. Full path should, in any cases, remove issue due to how the directory is looked up. Do you have an application.yml as well in the same directory?

Comment: @grekier i am able to run the app when i pass `--spring.config.location=../path/config/ --spring.profiles.active=local --spring.active.profiles=local` in eclipse `Run Configuration` `Program Arguments`.How can i execute the app with a command

Comment: You need to add a `D` to each of them I believe. `--Dspring.config.location=../path/config/ --Dspring.active.profiles=local`. Eclipse should show you the arguments as they are passed to the JVM in the console